# SSH/Fuse mount create file ok but can't delete it

Tags: ssh, debian, fuse, synology

I have a proxmox server so under debian, and I want to mount a remote directory from my Nas Synologies to make backups.
I normally use ssh mounts without any problem.

But this time I have an error that I have never encountered, I can create files, but not delete them.
I find this very strange and I don't see where this can come from

```
root@proxmox:/mnt/# sshfs user@192.168.0.1:home/data /mnt/dist-folder/ -o reconnect,
ServerAliveInterval=60,ServerAliveCountMax=30,allow_other,
default_permissions,uid=0,gid=0,umask=007
root@proxmox:/mnt# cd dist-folder/
root@proxmox:/mnt/dist-folder# touch aa.txt
root@proxmox:/mnt/dist-folder# ls -la
total 12
drwxrwx--- 1 root root  114 Mar 13 09:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Mar 13 09:37 ..
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root    0 Mar 13 09:53 aa.txt
root@proxmox:/mnt/dist-folder# rm aa.txt
rm: cannot remove 'aa.txt': Permission denied
```

> With uid=0,gid=0 for root user and group

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is finally a problem specific to synology.
For the assembly of the file it is absolutely necessary to respect the path by starting with

```
/homes/<user>home/
```

So it's give

```
sshfs user@192.168.0.1:/homes/proxmox/home/data /mnt/dist-folder/
```

And it's works fine !

It's not the first time that I have an abnormal configuration for this synology tool... AGrrrr